# requirejs module is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have following directory structure

```
scripts
    modules
        tabs.js
    app.js
```

I have following code in app.js

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore',
    'modules/tabs',
    ], function($, _, Tabs) {

    var App = (function() {

        var init = function() {
            console.log('app');
            Tabs.init();
        };

        return {
            init: init
        };

    }());

    return App;
});
```

following code in tabs.js

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore',
    '../app'
    ], function($, _, App) {

    var Tabs = (function() {

        var init = function() {
            console.log('tabs init');
            App.init();
        };

        return {
            init: init
        }

    }());

    return Tabs;

});
```

As it can be seen that both app.js dependent on tabs.js and tabs.js is dependent on app.js What happens is when I call Tabs.init() in app.js then it works fine but when I do App.init() in tabs.js then App is undefined. How can I make this work so that when I do App.init() in tabs.js then it should work?

Answer (score 5):

> If you define a circular dependency ("a" needs "b" and "b" needs "a"),
>   then in this case when "b"'s module function is called, it will get an
>   undefined value for "a". "b" can fetch "a" later after modules have
>   been defined by using the require() method (be sure to specify require
>   as a dependency so the right context is used to look up "a"):
>
> ```
> //Inside b.js:
> define(["require", "a"],
>     function(require, a) {
>         //"a" in this case will be null if "a" also asked for "b",
>         //a circular dependency.
>         return function(title) {
>             return require("a").doSomething();
>         }
>     }
> );
> ```

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular

Comment: You made my day! Thanks.