# RequireJS - Cannot Access External Module Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dependency-injection, requirejs

I'm having an issue with **RequireJS**. Essentially, I'm not able to access a function defined inside another file from another one.

I need to do that because I want to export a given subset of functions like

```
define('submodule', [], function() {

    let myFunction1 = function(){ return "Hello"; }
    let myFunction2 = function(){ return " From"; }
    let myFunction3 = function(){ return " Submodule!"; }

    return {
             myFunction1 : myFunction1,
             myFunction2 : myFunction2,
             myFunction3 : myFunction3,
    };

});
```

And accessing them from another file

```
define('main', ['config', 'sub1', 'sub2', 'submodule'],   
        function(config, sub1, sub2, submodule) {

  //Config
  alert(config.conf);

  //Submodule
  let callSubmodule = function() {
    alert(submodule.myFunction1() + 
          submodule.myFunction2() + 
          submodule.myFunction3());
  }

  //sub1
  let callSub1 = function() {
    alert(sub1.myFunction1());
  }

  //sub2
  let callSub2 = function() {
    alert(sub2.myFunction1());
  }

});
```

> The fact is that usually I'm able to do this with **sub1** and
>   **sub2**, but, with **submodule**, I simply can't. I think it's somehow caused by the dependencies in **require.config.js**.

My **require.config.js**:

```
require(['common'], function () { //contains vendors
    require(['config'], function () { //contains a js config file
        require(['main'], function () { //main file
            require(['sub1', 'sub2'], function () { //some subfiles
                require(['submodule']);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

For **submodule.myFunction1()** and othe two related functions I'm getting:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'myFunction1' of undefined

This is weird since I'm able to do that in other situations and I really can't understand why this is happening. For instance, I'm able to call **sub1** and **sub2** functions from main and other files but not **submodule** in particular.

**Index.html**

```
//Taken from Plunker
. . .
<script data-main="common"  data-require="require.js@2.1.20" data-semver="2.1.20" src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.20/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="require.config.js"></script>

. . .
<button onclick = "callSubmodule()">Call Submodule</button>
<button onclick = "callSub1()">Call Sub1</button>
<button onclick = "callSub2()">Call Sub2</button>
```

**common.js** contains vendors, here's just an example

```
requirejs.config({
   baseUrl : "",
    paths : {
             "jquery" : "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    }
});
```

**sub1.js**

```
define('sub1', ['submodule'], function(submodule) {

    let myFunction1 = function(){ return "called sub1"; }

    return {
             myFunction1 : myFunction1
    };

});
```

**sub2.js**

```
define('sub2', ['submodule'], function(submodule) {

    let myFunction1 = function(){ return "called sub2"; }

    return {
             myFunction1 : myFunction1
    };

});
```

I set up a [Plunker with @SergGr help](http://plnkr.co/edit/4HCEadkzkcjyvTr9VGcn) that tries to replicate application's structure but all the modules get undefined on click. On the real application this does not happen.

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: If my answer is *the* answer, your question looks like a double "oops" and should be deleted. I won't miss the rep. If you just made a transcription error when you wrote the question, you'll have to edit.

Comment: I'll take a look within tomorrow morning and I'll let you know ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: if you share your source on jsfiddle, it will be helpful to debug

Comment: Question: What does a 404 on your server look like? Is there a JS 404 vs an HTML 404? Does your server pass through and just try to serve static assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Managed to solve this issue. Essentially, it was caused by a *circular-dependency* between the modules. So, *a* needed *b* and *b* needed *a* leading to one of them being undefined on the dependency resolution.

I found a solution to that on the answer provided by @jgillich at [requirejs module is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819317/requirejs-module-is-undefined/24819391).

So, I managed to solve using, in main

```
define('main', ['config', 'sub1', 'sub2', 'require'],   
    function(config, sub1, sub2, submodule, require) {

  //Config
  alert(config.conf);

  //Submodule
  let callSubmodule = function() {
    alert(require('submodule').myFunction1() + 
          require('submodule').myFunction2() + 
          require('submodule').myFunction3());
  }

});
```

As @jgillich said:

> If you define a circular dependency ("a" needs "b" and "b" needs "a"), then in this case when "b"'s module function is called, it will get an undefined value for "a". "b" can fetch "a" later after modules have been defined by using the require() method (be sure to specify require as a dependency so the right context is used to look up "a"):

```
//Inside b.js:
define(["require", "a"],
    function(require, a) {
        //"a" in this case will be null if "a" also asked for "b",
        //a circular dependency.
        return function(title) {
            return require("a").doSomething();
        }
    }
);
```

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular

Comment: That would do it. It is really hard to debug circular dependencies in requirejs. I'd really recommend drawing the dependency graph of your architecture on paper and planning out your architecture in a way that would never make this happen. Then enforce rules that prevent you or anyone on your team from slipping into this issue. For instance, views can depend on models. Controllers can depend on views and models, but models can never depend on controllers (or something like that). Like I said, it is realllyyyy hard to debug. There are really no error messages for this either.

Comment: That's a precious advice you are giving me. I still hadn't think about drawing a schema of the situation. The real deal here is that It was given to me a big jsrender/jquery/js-vanilla project with no patterns and 3/4 files of 3k lines of code each. I come from AngularJS and It's pretty impossible to me to understand these milestones, so, I'm trying to modularize the project using require and other tools.

Answer (score 2):

This is your code:

```
define('main', ['submodule'], function(submod) {
   console.log(submodule.myFunction());
});
```

You have `submod` in the parameter list. But you then try to access `submodule`. Note that you return the function straight from your module (`return myFunction`), so your module has the value of the function `myFunction` and thus the module is what you should call. The code should be:

```
define('main', ['submodule'], function(submod) {
   console.log(submod());
});
```

Comment: If I try this approach I get `submod is not a function`. But, also, guess I-ve a module and I want to export lots of functions. I edit my Question.

Answer (score 2):

The way you've named your modules I would expect they all came from a require config file. I would not expect that requirejs would know how to load those files without some sort of explicit compilation process. I also suspect that your server is returning something due to a 404 that JS is almost able to interpret without exploding.

Your setup seems and naming scheme seems quite strange. If you have the ability to start from scratch below are my recommendations.

#### Recommendations:

- I'm noticing that you're using absolute paths. I highly recommend using relative paths for everything. There are many reasons for this.
- Your data-main should be what you call "require.config.js". Your common.js is actually a require.config.js.
- You load require.config.js (which is your main) separately using a script tag. You can do this but it's strange.
- You can use the "commonjs" style syntax to require files without needing to use the array to define all your dependencies. I recommend that.

#### This is my recommendation for a set-up:

index.html

```
<script src="/js/config.js" />
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.20/minified/require.js" />
<script>
      require('/js/main', function(main) {
          main({});
      });
</script>
```

/js/config.js

```
// setting requirejs to an object before its loaded will cause requirejs to use it as the config
window.requirejs = {
   baseUrl : "/",
    paths : {
        "jquery" : "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    }
};
```

/js/main.js

```
define(function(require) {
    const sum = require('./sum');
    return (a, b) => sum(a, b);
});
```

/js/sum.js

```
define(function(require) {
    return (a, b) => a + b;
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I use relative paths. In this example I just haven't put any of them. About setting up **require.config.js** in a separated js file and not into a `script` tag is just a way to keep a cleaner html code. About  `const sum = require('./sum');` that's an interesting approach but I noticed that sometimes It can't be done since I get: `module x has not been loaded yet`, so, I'm using `require('x').fun()` for that reason. Any hint on that?

Comment: @AndreaM16 you need to make sure to add the `require` as a parameter. Like this `define(function(require) {`

Comment: Yeah I made sure. When I'll be at work tomorrow I'll tell you exactly what's happening. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** (March 02, 2017)

Your plunker obviously will not work because you have direct calls from HTML to your module functions.

```js
<button onclick = "callSubmodule()">Call Submodule</button>
<button onclick = "callSub1()">Call Sub1</button>
<button onclick = "callSub2()">Call Sub2</button>
```

RequireJS doesn't work that way. One of key purposes of RequireJS is to provide modules isolation and thus it just can't work that way: imagine if several different modules had functions `callSubmodule`.

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to bind calls from HTML back to the code in a RequireJS module, it should be other way around: module binds to HTML. And if you fix those issues, everything works fine for me as you can see at this [fork of your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bSd8ZmUGwDOcNSmimdpO).

---

Old Answer

The bug is in your **subModule.js**

```js
define('submodule', [], function() {

    let myFunction = function(){ return "Hello"; }

    //return myFunction;     // old, wrong
    return { myFunction: myFunction }; 
});
```

Even if you want to return just 1 function you should not return it as is, you should wrap it into an object and give it an explicit name.

P.S. if this is not your real issuse, please provide us real [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I already specified under the edit what you are saying. I fixed the question so it's more clear from the beginning.

Comment: @AndreaM16, sorry but your question doesn't contain MCVE. It is at least not Complete and thus is not Verifiable

Comment: I don't get why you are thinking It. I'm not new to stackoverflow, and I know for sure these are the important things about requirejs configuration and module utilization and definition. The only thing is missing is the html where I Just requirejs both requirejs and its configuration. Be more clear in what you mean.

Comment: What is `sub1` and `sub2`? Is the issue reproducible without them? If yes, why are they in the example? If not, why you don't provide their content?

Comment: @AndreaM16 The same goes about all the other modules except for `main` and `submodule`

Comment: @AndreaM16, so here is my attempt to reproduce your issue with the data you provided http://plnkr.co/edit/aNES7mNmIIdOljJovJga?p=preview and it works OK

Comment: Tomorrow Morning I'll try to edit my question and the plunker. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @AndreaM16, see my updated answer for updated question